# How to set up git to let me and my kids manage a web server (what am I doing wrong? no files appear...)

Tags: ssh, centos, git

UPDATE - see later to glimpse my whole day.  See next for the TLDR; version...

TLDR; I've got 2 CentOS machines - "cork" (a web server) and "local" (one workstation for now).  ssh and hostnames etc are all working properly.  What do I need to type on "cork" to create a place where files get stored which is managed by "git", and what do I have to type on "local" to get git set up to use that, and finally, what do I need to do (in git) on "local" to cause a file created on "local" to arrive to "cork" ?

I've read a LOT of tutorials and related help - the problem is 100% "me" for sure, because I'm already an experienced coder; none of the doc or concepts I can read make any kind of sense to me.  Maybe I'm trying to do something (avoid github and use my own machine via CLI only) that's too obscure, because I can't find any examples anywhere of setup instructions for this kind of thing?

More detail:-

I've got a working CentOS stream webserver in cork.  On it, I did this:-

```
git init -bare myrepo.git
```

Next, on my local CentOS 8 workstation, I did this:-

```
$ mkdir dev
$ cd dev
$ git clone leo@cork:~/myrepo.git myrepo.git
$ cd myrepo.git/
$ pwd > sample.txt
$ git add sample.txt 
$ git commit -am "My First Commit"
1 file changed, 1 insertion(+), 1 deletion(-)

$ git push origin master
[snip]
Writing objects: 100% (3/3), 296 bytes | 296.00 KiB/s, done.
Total 3 (delta 0), reused 0 (delta 0), pack-reused 0
To cork:~/myrepo.git
   fee070c..f9bb90a  master -> master

$ dir
total 8
drwxrwxr-x. 3 leo leo  42 Aug 18 01:53 ../
drwxrwxr-x. 3 leo leo  51 Aug 18 01:56 ./
-rw-rw-r--. 1 leo leo  20 Aug 18 13:07 sample.txt
drwxrwxr-x. 8 leo leo 166 Aug 18 13:07 .git/
```

but when I look in my cork machine, the file is not there

```
$ dir ~/myrepo.git/
total 4
drwxrwxr-x.  3 leo leo   18 Aug 18 01:50 ./
drwxrwxr-x.  8 leo leo  131 Aug 18 01:58 .git/
drwxr-xr-x. 18 leo leo 4096 Aug 18 12:42 ../
```

*UPDATE*

I discovered that -bare creates a repo with the base name "are" (the 3 letters after the -b).  I deleted everything and redid with -b master.
Next, I discovered I had to do this:

```
git config --bool core.bare true
```

no change to my problem though - nothing is getting uploaded.

*UPDATE2*
tried all again using

```
git init --bare --shared grumble && cd $_
```

still no luck